# PHP MySQL - loop back through number until result found

Tags: php, mysql

I have some sql that searches a db table for a number from a form input.

An good example would be the following rows:

```
124
1240
12400
124000
```

My sql is a simple like statement:

```
SELECT NUMBER FROM TABLE WHERE NUMBER LIKE '$number%'
```

If the use searched for 124, I would get find 4 rows which is fine.

My question is, if the user typed in 12400000, how can I return the row with 124000?
I'm assuming that I would need to loop back through the number until a row is found?

My input requires a min of 3 numbers before the sql is run, so I would want to stop the loop at 3 numbers.

With php and or SQL, is there a method that allows me to count back on a string to a defined point; string back to the 3rd Character?

Comment: Sounds like a rather strange design.  What do these numbers represent?  What is the search attempting to retrieve?  Perhaps an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: The numbers a representative of phone numbers, I need to run a search for an input number to output details of that number. Some of the data only use 4-5 strings and some a full number. So, if someone were to copy and paste a full number into the form and the number in the table uses only part of that string, the query with the full number would not output any data, hence needing to loop back through the string until I find the first matching number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make an array from that input and use the `IN`:

```
$_POST['number'] = '124000';

$number = (string)(int)$_POST['number'];

$numbers = array();
$inNumber = '';
if(strlen($number) > 2){
    $baseNumber = substr($number, 0, 3);
    $numbers[] = $baseNumber;
    for($i=3; $i<=strlen($number)-1; $i++){
        $inNumber.= $number[$i];
        $numbers[] = $baseNumber.$inNumber;
    }

    $tosearch = implode("','", array_reverse($numbers));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `NUMBER` IN ('".$tosearch."') ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, '".$tosearch."')";
    echo $query; // SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `NUMBER` IN ('124000','12400','1240','124') ORDER BY FIELD(`NUMBER`, '124000','12400','1240','124')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this works well but not exactly how I would like it.

Comment: What I would really like to do is return one number. In this instance, I would like to stop searching once a match has been found.

Comment: For that you need to use multiple queries which is not ok. I've modified my scripts and will return the values in order and you just need to extract first result.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I'll give it a test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the str_replcace and remove the latest one in the case nothing is found.
More information: http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php

A better way would be to display that nothing is found using this search string